Bareword "help" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 2) line 1
Tried to understand but couldn't!
Iam using the rename package to change my BundleID for my flutter app. when I use "help" command in the Terminal:
rename help setBundleId
the structure of this is correct by following the usage of its homepage: pub.dev package. I try to get any detail of this command to use, 'cause when I try this command before:
rename setBundleId --targets android --value "com.example.bundleId"
I 've removed "--targets android" with my purpose is to apply all platform, but the result got back is "unknow option value".
So now, I need your help. My main purpose is to change BundleID for both ios and android platforrm for my flutter app.

try this it will change the bundle id

flutter pub global activate rename
flutter pub global run rename setBundleId --targets ios,android --value "com.example.bundleId"

